# Can you create a value referenced with dot "." python

Tags: python

I want to call a function that takes a class as an argument, without passing it a class.

The function only uses an integer value from the class, and the place I call it from has information that can calculate the value independently.

My code looks like:

Function I want to call:

```
    def buckets_from_pairs(fs_pairs,par):
        fsea=fermi_sea(par.N)

        # rest of function has no reference to par
```

Function I call from:

```
    def deltas(roots):
        if "buckets" in roots:
            # do function on    roots["buckets"]

        if "partition" in roots:
            #somehow define     value  such that  value.N=len(roots["roots"])

            buckets=buckets_from_pairs(roots["partition"], value)

            #do function on    buckets
```

I could change `deltas` to take `par` as an argument and I could change `buckets_from_pairs` to work without `par` but both would require a lot of reworking, and I would have to organise it with my supervisor who wrote both functions (he doesn't have this problem).

So I was hoping there was a simpler way of creating an object that can use the "dot" to reference something than creating a new class in the calling function.

Comment: Why does that value have to be contained inside an *object* (please try and use correct terminology)? Why can't you just pass an integer?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart The function I'm calling is one written by my supervisor and it's used in a bunch of modules I have nothing to do with - I honestly don't know why it's written that way, I'm just tying to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from collections import namedtuple
value = namedtuple('Value', 'N')(len(roots["roots"]))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make a little adapter like this:

```
class Adapter(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.N = n
```

Then:

```
buckets=buckets_from_pairs(roots["partition"], Adapter(len(roots["roots"]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just

```
def buckets_from_pairs(fs_pairs, N):
    fsea=fermi_sea(N)
```

called with

```
buckets=buckets_from_pairs(roots["partition"], value.N)
```

Comment: He wants to leave buckets... unmodified.

Comment: Sounds like any change to `buckets_from_pairs` would incur a lot of red tape, so the OP wants to avoid it if possible. "[it] would require a lot of reworking, and I would have to organise it with my supervisor"

Comment: That sounds like a recipe for bad programming. It seems @gnibbler has the noblest solution.

Answer (score 1):

@gnibbler answer is good and @John Zwinck had a good idea, but it can be made general:

```
class objval(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

par = objval(N=len(roots["roots"])
```

In general, `objval` allows you to create values wrapped in objects on the fly like:

```
o = objval(prop1=value1, prop2=value2)
```

Your choice of solution comes down to a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

If the value should be modifiable; you could use [types.SimpleNamespace](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace) class in Python 3.3+:

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

value = SimpleNamespace(N=len(roots["roots"]))
```

On older Python versions you could use [Adapter class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14959270/4279).

For read-only case; you could use [`namedtuple`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14959301/4279).